# Performance benefit of using buffer on heap over stack (C)

Tags: c, performance, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a small buffer of 1024 bytes that I am using to store temporary data in and then write to a larger buffer.  I am reusing that small buffer several times.

Is there any performance benefit to creating this buffer on the heap rather than the stack?

It's existing code so it was done on the heap but I'm not sure if it would be faster to use the stack or what exactly the reasoning was to using the heap in the first place.

Any ideas? This is C code.

Comment: measure it (on the systems this will run on, and with relevant work loads)

Comment: This is a great question.  Like @SanderDeDycker points out local measurements based on your OS, app, compiler, etc. will give you the best information.  Its difficult to provide a rock solid answer given the number of variables

Comment: @Hogstrom local measurements without thinking about the mechanisms behind it can vary with the circumstances and are not a reliable base for an implementation.

Comment: @ctx I concur.  My point is that the answer is more complicated than the simplicity of the question.  Its a great question, there is just not a slam dunk answer

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing code for a very small system, you may need to get the buffer using `malloc` (or one of the related routines, such as `calloc`) so that you do not use limited stack space.

Otherwise, on modern systems, 1024 bytes is a modest amount of stack space to use, and creating a buffer on the stack is typically faster than using `malloc`. (A normal `malloc` call requires at least some amount of bookkeeping work that stack allocation does not. However, if a routine merely allocates a fixed-size buffer with `malloc`, uses it, and frees it, a compiler might optimize the buffer to a stack allocation anyway, in which case they would be equivalent.)

For reference, on macOS, Apple’s tools default to 8 MiB of space for the main stack and 2 MiB for each thread.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "very small system", but microcontrollers etc with limited stack space don't even have a heap, and strongly discourage the use of one. Rather, they have completely variable memory segments. So if you would have 1kb data/bss, 1kb stack and 1kb heap, you lose 1kb just for having the heap, whether you use it or not. Where that 1kb could have been put to better use as data/bss or stack instead. Heaps only make sense on large systems where RAM is shared by multiple processes.

Answer (score 1):

In general, stack *allocation* is always faster than heap allocation.

This is because stack allocation is as easy as a single write to the stack pointer, whereas dynamic memory allocation contains a lot of overhead code during allocation - `malloc` has to go look for the next free segment, possibly also handling issues with fragmentation etc.

If you re-use a buffer, you should make sure to only allocate it once, no matter where you allocate it. This might be in favour of the heap, since heap-allocated variables don't go out of scope.

As for accessing memory once it is allocated, the stack and heap should perform identically.

Most importantly, allocating a large chunk of data on the stack isn't recommended, since it has a limited size. 1024 bytes is fairly large, so the recommended practice would be to store it on the heap for that reason alone.

Comment: I tend to disagree on your first sentence. malloc()ing such a small buffer can often be performed completely in userspace since there is enough reserved on the data segment. When the stack has to be grown, there is a page fault and the OS has to do the same (or similar) things as you describe it for malloc().

Comment: @Ctx Who said anything about an OS? You speak of very system-specific things not present in the question.

Comment: since you said "in general", I also tend to look at the most common case: the presence of a common OS. Since this should be the vast majority of the cases, you shouldn't ignore it, right?

Comment: @Ctx The most common case, in terms of CPUs on market, is bare metal embedded systems. Rather, it sounds like you speak of a PC because that's what you work with personally.

Comment: No, I speak of a PC, since this is the platform most programming questions here aim at and there is no hint in the question, that points in another direction. And if you do not assume anything about the target platform, writing an answer at all is nonsense anyway (especially nothing backs your first sentence then, too)

Comment: @Ctx, C is widely use in embedded systems, still the market leader in embedded system OS is Linux not PC windows.

Comment: @danglingpointer Yes, I was talking about Linux for example, which can behave exactly as I stated in my first comment.

Comment: @Ctx generally speaking there is nothing like user or kernel space from the C point of view. So your considerations are very implementation defined. THIS question is general and generally speaking moving the stack pointer **is faster** than calling the malloc function even if this function only returns a fixed value of the static buffer without any real allocations , checks etc etc

Comment: @Ctx you are very rude and I have reported you to the moderation. How to move stack pointer? Declare the automatic variable. https://godbolt.org/z/IqJ7vf

Comment: If I had a buffer of 30,000 bytes for example, would that be best suited on the heap then rather than stack due to the size?

Comment: @mocode10 Indeed the heap would be most suitable. Another option is the data segment, where variables end up if you declare them as `static`.